# Work out if 2022-01-14T20:56:55Z is a valid date time in Go

Tags: go

I am attempting to create a function that tells me if a timestamp is valid or not.

My function looks like

```
// IsTimestamp checks if a string contains a timestamp.
func IsTimestamp(str string) bool {
    _, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05.999", str)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

However, passing in `2022-01-14T20:56:55Z` returns false when is it a valid timestamp.

I'm thinking this might be something to do with the layout I am using in time.Parse but I've tried just using the date with no luck.

Comment: ""2006-01-02 15:04:05Z"

Comment: @Volker that comes back as false as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your layout doesn't match your input string, so it's expected that it isn't parsed successfully.

The [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Parse) say:

> Parse parses a formatted string and returns the time value it represents. See the documentation for the constant called Layout to see how to represent the format. The second argument must be parseable using the format string (layout) provided as the first argument.

Therefore, you should use a layout that's matching your input. Below, I am using [RFC3339](https://pkg.go.dev/time#RFC3339), which is the layout of your input string.

```golang
if _, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, str); err != nil {
    ...
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/_Q26NS2wwfy

Answer (score 0):

`2022-01-14T20:56:55Z` does not match the layout `2006-01-02 15:04:05.999` because:

- the layout expects a whitespace after day, not `T`
- the layout expects exactly three digits for milliseconds (only two are given `55`)
- the layout does not expect the timezone to be specified. `Z` is not a valid.

You can match `2022-01-14T20:56:55Z` with the layout `2006-01-02T15:04:05.99Z`, or `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z`. Or even better, use [The Fool's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72216737/4708219).